# Code won't run in new forms

Tags: c#, .net

I am new to .net development so there is probably something obvious I am missing.

When loading `Form4` with the code below, the code I programmed into `Form4` won't run when loaded.

```
Random rnd = new Random(); //Code that shows Form4.
F4 = new Form4();
F4.Show();
F4.Location = new Point(rnd.Next(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width), rnd.Next(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height));
//F4.ShowDialog();
```

Form4 code

```
private async void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{
    await Task.Delay(2000);
    label1.Text = "Deleting Viruses...";
    progressBar1.Value = 20;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    progressBar1.Value = 30;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    progressBar1.Value = 40;
    await Task.Delay(1000);
    progressBar1.Value = 60;
    await Task.Delay(500);
}
```

Comment: What code doesn't run ?

Comment: `Show` and `ShowDialog` after one another makes no sense. Use either one.

Comment: Which code in Form4 doesn't execute? Which event of Form4 that code should be executed by?

Comment: Didn't mean to put showdialog there.. Same result even without showdialog there, so just ignore it.

Comment: `private async void Form4_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Delay(2000);
            label1.Text = "Deleting Viruses...";
            progressBar1.Value = 20;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            progressBar1.Value = 30;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            progressBar1.Value = 40;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
            progressBar1.Value = 60;
            await Task.Delay(500);
}`

Unsure why the code looks messed up like that in the comment. :/

Comment: you need to add the codes into your question

Comment: Have you confirmed with the debugger that the code is not running? Or do you simply assume that because you don't see the expected results?

Comment: Let me guess. Does the progress bar  show 60% when the Form is displayed?

Answer (score 0):

I'm making a guess here that your code is a joke application intended to create loads of these windows forever once the application is loaded (judging from the random location being used for the `Location` of `Form4`).

The key bit is where you're putting your first section of code.

If you've tried putting it in your `Form4_Load` method, you've probably found that the application throws a `System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception`, "Error creating window handle."

My best guess is that there's a limitation in Winforms preventing it from creating a new window handle for a Form when it's just created (or is just about to create) a window handle for a Form that it has yet to show.  My disclaimer here is that I don't know how this works internally, so this paragraph is guesswork.

If my assumption about your code is correct, you'll want to move your code to a different event, such as the [Shown](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.form.shown) event, like so:

```
private void Form4_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Random rnd = new Random(); //Code that shows Form4.
    F4 = new Form4();
    F4.Show();
    F4.Location = new Point(rnd.Next(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Width), 
    rnd.Next(0, Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds.Height));
}
```

The rest of your code that was already in `Form4_Load()` should be fine as it is.

It's worth noting that this will be rather irritating for the user that is unfortunate enough to run your application.  It might be worth adding a counter into your Form that limits the application to only creating 100 other `Form4` instances, eg:

```
private static int counter = 0;
```

And then, in your `Form4_Shown` event, you would do `counter++;` at the bottom, and then you would wrap the code creating the new `Form4` instance in an if check doing something like `if(counter < 100)`.

Comment: I tried Form4_Shown already, will do some more testing on it. :)

Also, it's random because the code is copied from another part that spams about 50 "viruses" before the "antivirus" (form4) pops up.

Comment: Ah right.  So am I right in thinking that what you really want is for `Form4` to appear after those 50 other windows appear?  If so, you could use the `counter` I mentioned in my answer (altering the code that spawns `Form4` to spawn the pretend 'virus' windows), but after it gets above a certain number (such as 50), you have an `else` statement that spawns the final `Form4` window.